# Let $K \subset [0,1]$ be the Cantor set. show that $f : [0, 1] \to \mathbb R$...

Tags: real-analysis, integration, solution-verification, measurable-functions, cantor-set

> Let $K \subset [0,1]$ be the Cantor set. show that $f : [0, 1] \to \mathbb R$ given by $$f(x) = \begin{cases} 1, & x \in K \\
>                        0, & x \in [0, 1]\setminus C \end{cases}$$ is integrable and calculate $\int_0^1 f(x)dx$.

My attempt:

The Cantor set $K$, although not countable, has a null measure. Thus, if we stop $n$-th step of its construction, we will see that the Cantor set is contained in the collection of $2^n$ intervals, each having length $\frac{1}{3^n}$.Given $ \epsilon \gt 0$, we can take $n \in \mathbb N$ such that $\frac{2}{3^n} \lt \epsilon$ and we conclude that the measure of $K$ is zero.

Now, as [ 0.1] is closed then $[0,1] - K$ is open, the function $f$ is locally constant, and therefore continues, at points $x \notin K$. Since $K$ has no interior points, $f$ is discontinued at all $K$ points. By the theorem(If every set D of the discontinuity points of a bounded function $f:[a,b] \to \mathbb R$ has null measure then $f$ is integrable) $f$ is integrable.

Given any partition $P$ of [0,1] all ranges of $P$ contain points that do not belong to $K$, since int $K = \emptyset$. Thus, $m_i=0$ and $s(f;p)=0$ for every partition $P$. It then follows that $\int_0^1 f(x)dx = \underline\int_0^1f(x)dx = 0$.

Thank's in advance for any help.

Comment: Is there any specific question you have about your argument? Perhaps a part you aren’t sure about?

Comment: @Clayton I'm not sure about anything.But more specifically if the calculation of the integral is correct.

Comment: Where you say "$\frac 2{3^n} < \epsilon$", it should be $\frac {2^n}{3^n}$. And earlier in that paragraph "Thus" should be "Because". "Thus" indicates you are taking what you just said as true and are using it to show what you are about to say. But what you follow it with is the proof that $K$ has null measure.

Comment: Also, when you start involving "measure", the word "integrable" no longer specifically means "Riemann Integrable". In fact, it more commonly means "Lebesgue integrable" in that context. So you need to be clear which form integrability you are referring to.